# find words out of vocabulary

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, vocabulary, oov

I have some texts in a pandas dataframe `df['mytext']`
I have also got a vocabulary `vocab` (list of words).

I am trying to list and count the words out of vocabulary for each document

I have tried the following but it is quite slow for 10k documents.

How to quickly and efficiently quantify the out of vocabulary tokens in collection of texts in pandas?

```
OOV_text=df['mytext'].apply(lambda s: ' '.join([ word  for word in s.split() if (word not in vocab) ]))
OOV=df['mytext'].apply(lambda s: sum([(word in vocab) for word in s.split()])/len(s.split()))
```

df.shape[0] is quite large
len(vocab) is large
len(unique words in df.mytext)<<len(vocab)

Comment: Do you have to know the count in every row, or you can do that for the entire DF?

Comment: I would need the row-wise quantification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
from collections import Counter
vocab=['word1','word2','word3','2021']
df['mytext_list']=df['mytext'].str.split(' ')
df['count']=df['mytext_list'].apply(lambda c:sum([Counter(c)[w] for w in vocab]))
```

It should be faster than your solution because it uses pandas vectorization and then the Counter method.

You can skip saving the helper column as "mytest_list" for saving memory usage.

Comment: This seems slower than the original